# Understanding choice functions - Teichmüller-Tukey Proof

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

There is a proof that the Teichmüller-Tukey lemma implies AC that seems to work in the following way:

1. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be any family of nonempty sets.
2. Consider $\mathcal{E}$={$f$: $f$ is a choice function for some subfamily $\mathcal{F}'\subseteq \mathcal{F}$}
3. Since $f$ is a choice function if and only if every finite subfunction is a choice function, $\mathcal{E}$ has finite character.
4. Therefore, by Teichmüller-Tukey lemma, $\mathcal{E}$ has a maximal element, say $f_{\max}$.
5. Since $f_{\max}$ is maximal, we have $\operatorname{dom}(f_{\max})=\mathcal{F}$. Hence, $f_{\max}$ is a choice function of $\mathcal{F}$.

Now, my question is:

> How can we consider the set of partial choice function without knowing
>   that there are choice functions?

Extra question:

> How can we define a choice function on finite families of sets without
>   the axiom of choice?

Comment: The extra question is a duplicate that was asked so many times before on this site. (And in any case, avoid "extra questions".)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, this was not the best structure of a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that there are always lots of *partial* choice functions on any family of nonempty sets: the empty function is always a partial choice function (:P), and less trivially if we fix a single set $A$ in the family and a single element $a$ of $A$, the function $\{(A, a)\}$ - with domain $\{A\}$, sending $A$ to $a$ - is a partial choice function.

But regardless, *we don't need to know that a set is nonempty in order to consider it.* Take any family $\mathcal{F}$ of nonempty sets; then ZF (indeed, much less) proves that there is a set $C$ consisting of all choice functions on $\mathcal{F}$. ZF does **not** prove, in general, that $C$ is nonempty; but it does prove that $C$ exists.

---

As to proving finite choice, this is a nice argument. By induction on **finite** $n$, ZF proves: "For all finite $n$, every family of $n$-many nonempty sets has a choice function." The induction goes like this:

- The base case is trivial.
- Now suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of $(n+1)$-many nonempty sets, and every family of $n$-many sets has a choice function. Fix some $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and let $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}\setminus\{A\}$. Then $\mathcal{G}$ has a choice function (by the induction hypothesis); pick a choice function $g$. Now fixing some $a\in A$, let $f=g\cup\{(A, a)\}$ (that is, $f$ extends $g$ to all of $\mathcal{F}$ by sending $A$ to $a$); it's easily checked that $f$ is a choice function.

The key to this proof is in the steps: "fix some $A\in\mathcal{F}$" and "fixing some $a\in A$." One of the rules of first-order logic is [**existential instantiation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation); we may always make, as a step in a proof, a *single* choice from some set we've proved is nonempty. So what's going on here is: *in order to prove finite choice in ZF, we've used the fact that the rules of first-order logic allow us to make two choices in the course of a proof* (namely, the choices of $A$ and $a$ above). In a sense, we could say that **finite choice is built into first-order logic**; this is missing an important point (see below), but isn't a bad first intuition.

This suggests, by the way, that we can view (versions of) the axiom of choice as *representing a logical rule beyond the usual rules of first-order logic*. Interestingly, this isn't the only time this crops up: **axioms of determinacy** can also be so viewed. Roughly speaking, saying "Every game on $X$ is determined" is equivalent to saying $$\forall x_1\exists x_2\forall x_3\exists x_4 ...[P(x_1x_2x_3x_4...)]\quad\vee\quad\exists x_1\forall x_2\exists x_3\forall x_4 ...[\neg P(x_1x_2x_3x_4...)]$$ where the quantifiers range over $X$, whenever $P$ is a property of sequences of elements of $X$. And this is sort of an "infinitary" version of [De Morgan's laws for quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic).

Fascinatingly, even when we take $X=\{0, 1\}$ [the resulting determinacy principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) contradicts the axiom of choice; and the statement "determinacy holds *for all sets $X$*" is outright disprovable in ZF. So there's an interesting tension between some plausible logical rules beyond first-order logic. If I recall correctly, this is treated somewhat at the end of [Takeuti's book on proof theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486490734), but it's been a while since I read it and I don't have it on me.

---

Now let me say a bit about why the slogan "ZF proves finite choice since finite choice is built into the rules for first-order logic" is actually missing an important point:

Remember that saying "ZF proves $\varphi$" means "$\varphi$ is true in every model of ZF" (this is the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem)). Now when we express finite choice in ZF, the word "finite" gets *interpreted*: any model of ZF has a collection of things it thinks are the natural numbers, and "finite" for that model means "in bijection with some finite natural number" *from the point of view of that model*.

But [there are models of ZF which "get the natural numbers wrong."](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40821/existence-of-an-omega-nonstandard-model-of-zfc-from-compactness) In such a model, there will be a collection of nonempty sets $\mathcal{F}$ which the model thinks is finite but is not actually finite. But since ZF proves finite choice, there will be a choice function for that family in the model, *even though that family isn't really finite*. So what's actually going on is that somehow *external* finite choice being built into first-order logic means that *internal* finite choice - a stronger principle - is provable in ZF. This ultimately is a kind of "overspill" argument, and diving too deep into what's going on here would take us well astray; but it's important to note that the short slogan I gave above isn't really the whole picture.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful and interesting! Just two questions: In the base case of the induction you already use the principle you're explaining after - we pick an element of the non-empty only set of the family by existential instantiation (by knowing it to be non-empty)? Considering the non-standard models: How would you define "true finiteness"? Considering that these sets would be finite in the model but "not actually finite",.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege "In the base case of the induction you already use the principle you're explaining after - we pick an element of the non-empty only set of the family by existential instantiation (by knowing it to be non-empty)?" No - in the base case, and in the induction step, we use the *logical rule* of existential instantiation. All we need to apply this to a set $x$, is the knowledge that $x$ is nonempty: in the course of a proof, if we have already proved that $x$ is nonempty, then we may introduce a new symbol standing for an element of $x$ (that is, pick an element of $x$). (cont'd)

Comment: @GottlobtFrege "Considering the non-standard models: How would you define "true finiteness"? Considering that these sets would be finite in the model but "not actually finite"" Inside a model of ZF, all we can do is define what *that model* thinks "finite" means. When we talk about "true" finiteness, we do some from the point of view of some "true" universe of sets. (That's the Platonist take; we can make this purely formalist of course, but understanding the Platonist view is a good first step in my opinion: while I find Platonism hard to defend, it's a useful conceptual tool.)

Comment: I can promise you that finding all the duplicates *and* related questions on finite choices would have taken less time than typing the whole thing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I actually wasn't completely satisfied with any of the answers I found; I really wanted one that both gave the slogan "finite choice is provable in ZF since it's built into first-order logic" and went into the subtleties of that slogan. Since I couldn't find one, I made one. (Also, any excuse to reference Takeuti is a good one.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is a choice function from the empty family, which is a subfamily of $\cal F$.

Moreover, if $f$ is a partial choice function and $A\in\mathcal F\setminus\operatorname{dom}(f)$, then given any $a\in A$, we get that $f\cup\{(A,a)\}$ is also a choice function from a subfamily of $\cal F$.

This argument is not only the key to proving that any finite family of non-empty sets admits a choice function, but also in proving that a maximal element of $\cal E$ is necessarily a choice function from the entire family $\cal F$.